# file separator in place of forward slashes in path in java

Tags: java

I have the below property code in my java class

```
certificateDerFile = System.getProperty("catalina.base")
                + "//logs//Cert_patch.der";
```

Now my query is that in the path  "//logs//Cert_patch.der", it should be refactored such // slashes should not be there should be some file separator which should work both in windows and Linux, please advise how to achieve the same.

Comment: I don't believe you have to escape normal slashes, only backslashes.

Comment: You don't need to escape `/`, you only need to escape ```\``` in Java. And on Windows you can use both `/` and ```\``` as a path separator.

Answer (score 1):

```
File.separator is either / or \ that is used to split up the path to a spec
ific file. For example on Windows it is \ or C:\Documents\Test
```

For example:

```
String path = File.separator + "var"+ File.separator + "temp"
```

Linux:
`/var/temp`

Windows:
`\var\temp`

Comment: request you to please convert the same as I have posted

Comment: @yrturgjririohrjkrh Why do you need the particular path from your question? IMHO this answer is fairly clear. Can you explain why your path is different?